# Android Calendar Provider API Level

Tags: android, calendar

We are developing an Android calendar app. The problem is that we want to get the events of other calendars and share our event to them too. As I have read this is achieved by a content provider.

The problem is that the API level required by calendar content provider is API 14 and we need to use it in API 7(Android 2.1). I have seen apps that do that in Android 2.1.

How can we achieve that?

Comment: Which applications are? I have understood exactly the same.

Comment: the default calendar of android does it, i have downloaded a lot of apps, and if i change something at them then the android default calendar has the new events i added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calendar provider is there but the API is not public before API level 14 and the authority may vary from device to device.  Here are some examples: [Is there a way to access the calendar's entries without using gdata-java-client?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/846942/1127492)