# How to get calendar page in my Android application?

Tags: android, calendar

I am using this code in my application and getting following page.

```
Intent calendarIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);  
            calendarIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            calendarIntent.putExtra("title", "Title");
            calendarIntent.putExtra("beginTime", new Date());
            calendarIntent.putExtra("endTime", new Date(2013,7,7));
            calendarIntent.putExtra("description", "Description");

            startActivity(calendarIntent);
```

[image]

but I want this page

[image]

what should I change in my code.
please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    long startMillis;
    ...
    Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
    builder.appendPath("time");   
    ContentUris.appendId(builder, startMillis);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(builder.build());
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: in this  Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
line gives an error `CalendarContract` cannot be resolved.

Comment: try importing  android.provider.CalendarContract

Comment: same error in `importing android.provider.CalendarContract` also

Comment: CalendarContract is for API Level 14+

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199979/android-calendar-proider-only-for-api-level-14-or-higher

Comment: @JigneshAnsodariya Right Click your project. Click "Properties" then click "Android" change your Project Build Target to Android 4.0.3 or into the latest version you've got.